# What is needed to build an ipa for Enterprise Distribution? (iOs - iPhone - iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, deployment, enterprise

I'm working on a project that will be distributed by a company internally.
So, I've been doing some research about this, and all the tutorials and guides starts on having the build (.ipa file).

The question is how to sign the code the way my client can distribute the app internally using enterprise distribution and not giving me his certificates?

Answer (score 5):

The Enterprise program Distribution certificates (and private keys) are needed to sign an app for enterprise distribution.  Either the client can trust you with the needed keys, or you can send the project to the client for final build, or the client can re-sign a compiled app bundle.

An app can be re-signed using the Mac OS X command-line; running Xcode 4 is not required.

Comment: so I build the app with my certificates and then the client has to resign the build... So I'll google the command line solution... I'll appreciate if you can send me a link to some kind of tutorial.. thanks!

Comment: The Xcode build window can display the codesign command-line it used after you do any Distribution build.

Answer (score 2):

To see an example of an unsigned version of code and instructions on loval code signing see http://easewiki.apperian.com/index.php/Code_Signing

This method enables command line signing on any Mac.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. You either have to give the client your code and let him compile/sign it or your client needs to give you his distribution certificate and the enterprise distribution profile so you can sign it.

If you're using Xcode4, you *could* sign it using some ad hoc and then share the actual archive bundle. A developer at your client's site could then import the archive bundle into his/her copy of Xcode4 and re-sign it with the appropriate certs. Given Xcode4 is still in beta, tho, who knows if that will work properly or if it will even still exist when it goes live.

Comment: I'll try that way, by the other hand if the available xcode 4 is not the final release, maybe the command line solution should be more secure. thanks for the answer!

Comment: For future readers, this is no longer valid, IPA's can be re-signed by the client, and it is also worth noting that if you sign it for them, you will have to re-sign it every 12 months with their new enterprise profile